# tooltip is not shown properly onmouse over

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, google-visualization

I am working on angularjs google charts. I want to show the horizontal scrollbar for the chart and it should be by default **scrolled from right to left**.

Working demo before applying css code to scroll from right to left (tooltip on mouseover is shown as expected) : 
[Working Demo before horizontal scrollbar is applied from right to lefft](http://plnkr.co/edit/SwEUeCN8IoT0JN5RrvUx?p=preview)

Demo after applying css code to scroll from right to left
[Demo, tooltip is not showing as expected when mouseover on the bar](http://plnkr.co/edit/1e0521rzenpiu3ZaLSUP?p=preview)

html code:

```
 <div ng-controller="myController" style="width:100%;height:50%;margin-left:0;white-space: nowrap;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden;direction:rtl;left:0;top:0;">
   <div style="width:90%;height:90%;" google-chart chart="myChart">
   </div> </div>
```

css code:

```
div[aria-label="A tabular representation of the data in the chart."] {
  left: 0 !important;}
```

Issue is with tooltip onmouse over on the bar, any inputs?

Comment: Why are you using Angular 1.3.0 beta?

Comment: @JorgeValle - angularjs (angular 1.0)

Comment: I understand that, but why are you loading a beta version from the CDN? If you are starting a clean project, I'd use the latest 1.6.x release.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the div containing the Chart to:

```
 <div style="width:100%;height:50%;margin-left:0;white-space: nowrap;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden;right:0;top:0;">
```

You can test it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/GjYPJC90NbMiLub6n1D1?p=preview).

Comment: I want the horizontal scrollbar to scroll from right to left and the issue exists when i used direction:rtl; Your answer doesn't fulfill my requirement(i want the horizontal scroll bar to be scrolled from right to left as mentioned in my post).@Lucas Rodriguez